# In NodeJS, using express and sequelize , if a model gives empty rows , then how to trigger a failed promise using .then()

Tags: node.js, express, promise, sequelize.js

If a model returns more than 1 row, shows a valid message along with result, and if the model returns 0 rows shows Invalid status.

this is what I have tried

```
checkValidityByAppId: (req,res) => {
  models.license_purchases.findAndCountAll({
    where: {application_id: req.query.application_id}
  }).then(result => {
          res.json({result:result,valid:"valid"})
      }
    )

}
```

Comment: I would do an if statement (int the "then" block) and in the event of failure use Promise.reject("Put some reason here");

Comment: @MikeWight can we write 'if-else' statement in 'then'. Can u please show me how?

Comment: @Pashmeena you can also throw an error(inside callback of then) when rows are empty, this thrown error will trigger error event of promise.

Comment: Something like this. 
then (result => { if (result > 0) {res.json({result: result, valid: "valid"})} else { Promise.reject("No rows found!")})

Comment: @MikeWight Thankyou so much for clarifying it. That solved the problem.

Comment: @KlwntSingh I googled it further, that 'error' mechanism was helpful, thankyou (y)